# Laravel admin area

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, admin, laravel-routing

working on a basic template for all future projects and decided to use Laravel.

The aim is just to create a starting point for any websites I make in the future (basic blog, admin area + user login system).

I was following a tutorial on the CRUD basics and made a simple blog management app. However I wish to put this into an /admin area.

Before, I had this in my route:

```
Route::resource('blog', 'BlogController');
```

Which then allowed me to simply use the functions in my BlogController on the domain.com/blog URL.

This is all working, but I want to mask this behind an admin area. I thought I could just move the blog folder with all my blog views in, into a admin folder but hitting route not defined errors.

The views folder is:

```
- Views

  - admin

    - blog
      - edit.blade.php
      - index.blade.php
      - new.blade.php
      - show.blade.php

  - home.blade.php
```

Before, my blog folder was simply in the views folder itself. What do I need to change to get domain.com/admin/blog working the same as it did before?

**Using Laravel 4.2**

Comment: Are you using Laravel 4 or 5?

Comment: 4.2, added to question. Keep forgetting 5 is out...

Comment: No worries. It only recently came out. It just helps to clarify for answers :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could group controllers together to be inside admin folder and this will be a lot easier for managing files.

## Laravel 5 Example

**routes.php**

```
Route::group(array('namespace' => 'admin', 'prefix' => 'admin'), function() {
  Route::resource('blog', 'BlogController');
});
```

and then you can create **BlogController.php** inside admin folder

```
/app/Http/Controllers/admin/BlogController.php
```

the example of **BlogController.php** file

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class BlogController extends Controller {

  public function index()
  {
    echo "admin/blog/index";
  }
}
```

and then you can call `http://localhost:8000/admin/blog`

## Laravel 4 Example

**routes.php**

```
Route::group(array('namespace' => 'admin', 'prefix' => 'admin'), function() {
  Route::resource('blog', 'BlogController');
});
```

and then you can create **BlogController.php** inside admin folder

```
/app/controllers/admin/BlogController.php
```

the example of **BlogController.php** file

```
<?php namespace Admin;

class BlogController extends \BaseController {

  public function index()
  {
    echo "admin/blog/index";
  }
}
```

and then you can call `http://localhost:8000/admin/blog`

Comment: @DesignerGuy Thank you very much, this is lot better in both English and coding.

Comment: Thanks Ill have a go with this.

Comment: I think the main laravel 4 difference from this answer would be the namespace-related code and changes.